# Inserting a concatenated string to DB gets truncated

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, concatenation, truncation

I made a simple modification to the way I insert a new user to the DB(**DataBase SQL Server 2008**). instead of the user entering his full email(username@domain.com) the user is ordered to enter the username alone and then it is completed to a full email address in the code like so:

```
User.createUser(tbFirstName.Text, tbLastName.Text, tbEmail.Text + "@domain.com");
```

the function createUser isn't changed, snippet:

```
db sql = new db();
sql.command = @"insert into users(first_name, last_name, email) values(@firstname, @lastname, @email)";
sql.addParam("@firstname", firstname);
sql.addParam("@lastname", lastname);
sql.addParam("@email", email);
sql.nonQuery();
```

**addParam, which is implemented in class db, does what the name says:**

```
public void addParam(SqlParameter param)
{
    _command.Parameters.Add(param);
}
public void addParam(string name, object value)
{
    addParam(new SqlParameter(name, value));
}
```

**when:**

```
SqlCommand _command;
```

**is a member in class db.**

now when I fill a new user form and type in "user" in tbEmail, the text is concatenated with "@domain.com" as needed and the Param's value is correct, but when executing the SQL command, only the text "user" is inserted into the DB, the rest(@domain.com) is truncated(**the field in the DB is of nvarchar(max)**).

Why is this happening? what's the difference from before this modification? how do I fix it?
Thanks in advance
**EDITED.**

Comment: Show how `addParam` works.

Comment: How are chances your `email` field is just to short?

Comment: @ZoolWay and Wiktor Zychla the post has been edited.

Comment: If this really is the complete correct code it should work. Any chance you did not copy everything? Also `sql.nonQuery()` will execute `ICommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` I guess from your code. Code you just stop at that line with a breakpoint and take a look at `_command.Parameters` and `_command.CommandText` just before execution?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the column size of the table. Probably your column might not be sufficient to accommodate the new size